# Как считать количество дочерних директорий и печатать каждую на новой строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такая структура папок:

[image: Структура]

[скриншот структура](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Uag5.png)

Каким образом реализовать вывод на экран в json формате всех папок, следующих после **Connections**?
Т.е, хочу результат в таком виде:

```
{ 
 Anyway {
     HTTPS {
      Identity }
        }
}

{ BillingGateway {
              HTTPS {
                  Identity }
                 }
}

{ EMS {
       Data
      }
}

{ EMS {
      External
      }
}
```

Comment: в вашем вопросе невалидный json - поправьте, если хотите чтобы вам помогли

Comment: @EugeneDennis вроде валидный, в чем некорректность, подскажите пож. Но краткая суть в том, что все директории идущие после Connections - должны печататься на новой строке.

Comment: На новой строке чего? В формате json нет новых строк, там вообще все может быть в одну строку.

Comment: @Эникейщик ок, можно в одну строку, не вопрос. Переносы я добавлю Сам, но как тягать папки, это вопрос.

Comment: Можно брать путь как строку, обрезать ненужное в начале, потом делать ``split()`` оставшейся части по ``\`` и собирать json.

Comment: @Эникейщик в моем текущем скрипте, набор путей сохранен как список, и необходимо каждую строку списка обработать. Если бы было одинаковое количество элементов (директорий) в пути, то я бы просто сделал split('/')[1], условно.

Comment: Так а в чем проблема-то? Берем каждую строку по очереди, отрезаем ненужное начало. Потом сплитом разделяем на части и складываем в джейсон. split() возвращает список.